# "Application doesn't respond" but command sends output anyway (discord.py slash commands)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making slash commands for discord bot in dicord.py and when command is executed it shows that app doesn't respond but sends command output anyway. What is wrong?

Command's code:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="ping", description="Check bot's latency.")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(f"``Pong! {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms``  ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a defer command. For application commands, you must first defer and then followup afterwards if the interaction takes longer than 3 seconds. The library can handle this automatically for you in hybrid commands using Context.typing().

```
@bot.tree.command(name="ping", description="Check bot's latency.")
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.defer(ephemeral=True)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"``Pong! {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms``  ")
```

Also might be worth to use

```
ctx.reply
```

Instead of

```
ctx.channel.send
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using application command, so there should be `interaction`. There is no ctx for application command.
Do something like:

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="ping", description="Check bot's latency")
async def ping(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"``Pong! {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms``  ")
```

See more examples [here](https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f) 
If you want to keep both application command and traditional command (before dpy2.0 with ctx), consider using [hybrid command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=hybrid#discord.ext.commands.Bot.hybrid_command)